# Using sockets in multithread server

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, segmentation-fault, pthreads

guys!

I'm developing multithread server on c under *nix. In the main thread of the process I have listening socket which waits for connections (accept). When it gets a connection (accept returns client socket descriptor) I start new pthread whith some routine, which answers the request and closes client socket descriptor. It looking something like this:

```
while(1)
{
    sock_cl =(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *sock_cl = accept(sock_serv, NULL, NULL);
    pthread_create(thread, attr, answer, sock_cl);
}
```

answer function:

```
void *answer(void *arg)
{
    int sock_cl;
    char *buf;
    ssize_t r;
    lsres_t *ans;
    char *path;
    char status[STATUS_SIZE];

    sock_cl = *((int *)arg);
    if((buf = (char *)malloc(BUF_SIZE + 1)) == NULL)
    {
        sprintf(status, "%i\n", -1);
        send_data(sock_cl, status, STATUS_SIZE);
        close(sock_cl);
        free(arg);
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(buf, '\0', BUF_SIZE + 1);

    if((r = recv(sock_cl, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0)) <= 0)
    {
        close(sock_cl);
        free(arg);
        return NULL;
    }

    path = strtok(buf, "\r\0");
    if((ans = lscreate()) == NULL)
    {
        sprintf(status, "%i\n", -1);
        send_data(sock_cl, status, STATUS_SIZE);
    }
    else
    {
        if(myls(path, ans) != 0)
        {
            sprintf(status, "%i\n", -1);
            send_data(sock_cl, status, STATUS_SIZE);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(status, "%i\n", ans->status);
            send_data(sock_cl, status, STATUS_SIZE);
            send_data(sock_cl, ans->buf, ans->written_size);
        }
        lsdestroy(ans);
    }

    close(sock_cl);
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}
```

In answer function I call recv to recive data from client and send some answer. It works fine under Linux systems (Arch, Debian, Ubuntu), but when I try to run it under Unix (Solaris), I get a Segmentation fall in recv function. The problem is not in buffer, because if i try to call answer function in the same thread as answer function, I have no Segmentation fall. So there is some issue in using sockets with pthreads.

Please, advice me any solution how to use sockets in multithread server. Thank's for the future answers!

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris, you generally need to compile with `-mt` to correctly compile and link a multithreaded program.  If you don't use it, you'll get random crashes in threads like you see.

Comment: This key is suitable for cc. I'm using gcc with following keys:
-lpthread -D_REENTRANT -lrt -lsocket  -lnsl

Answer (score 0):

I think in unix recv function fails and the segmentation faut is due to the code segment `free(args);`

Comment: No even without free segmentation fault occures.

Comment: please check sock_cl  is valid in answer()

Comment: also I think sock_cl = (int)(*arg); is enough instead of sock_cl = *((int *)arg);

Comment: please declare the variable sock_cl as global and use it in threads. Now there is no need of passing it as argument.

Answer (score -1):

May be this could be the reason

```
   close(sock_cl);
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
```

This sock_cl is shared among threads and because there is no synchronization for the answer function and because you are freeing this pointer other threads bound to crash, if possible you check this same program in by running in valgrind for corruption.

Comment: I think it is not a reason, because each thread gets it's own pointer to sock_cl (it is malloc on each iteration in while). Threads have different pointers.