# Using pthreads and malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, malloc, solaris

I asked a question [Using sockets in multithread server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508466) yesterday. In this question I described segmentation fault under Solaris in multithreaded server. Now I have found the core of error and written code, that shortly demonstrates it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_attr_t *attr;

    attr = (pthread_attr_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t));
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    malloc(0);
    malloc(0); //Segmentation fault there

    return 0;
}
```

Second malloc crashes with Segmentation fault.
While this code executes normally:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_attr_t *attr;

    attr = (pthread_attr_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t));
    // pthread_attr_setdetachstate(attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    malloc(0);
    malloc(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please explain the reason of the error?

P.S.: I compile with `gcc -pthreads -lpthread -D_REENTRANT` keys.

Comment: What is the return value of setdetachstate?

Comment: Is this solaris machine again ? , by the way int main(int argc, int *argv[]) has to be char *argv[]

Comment: Do you have a particular reason not to initialize `attr` with the `pthread_attr_init` as documented (at least in my manual page)?

Comment: Aren't you missing to initialise what `attr` is pointing to by a call to `pthread_attr_init()`?

Comment: In full code I initialize `attr` with the `pthread_attr_init` of course. This pice of code just demonstrates that call of `pthread_attr_setdetachstate` causes some stranges in execution.

Comment: Does the the code you posted crash? Does it also crash if using `pthread_attr_init()`? Do all system calls perform without error? Does it compile without erros/warnings even without casting `malloc()`?

Comment: @alk I tried it and it does crash as above. If the `pthread_attr_init` is added however, the crash is gone.

Comment: Well it seems the problem may not be with pthread_attr_init because as per reference this should affect the thread which will be created using attributes, so i believe the problem could be with malloc which version of kernel you are using..?

Comment: So you solved the problem., at least the one described in this posting.

Comment: I bet if you ran your crashing code using Valgrind it'll give you an error while executing `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()` and it won't if you`d have called `pthread_attr_init ()` before.

Comment: Thank's everybody! The reason of the error is that I was calling pthread_attr_detachstate before pthread_attr_init. So obvious and simple!

Comment: @tegoo Please, write an answer up and accept it for the sake of the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs on `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.html):

> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the attr argument to pthread_attr_getdetachstate() or pthread_attr_setdetachstate() does not refer to an initialized thread attributes object.

It's possible that the `pthread_attr_t` object the `attr` argument points to contains a pointer to some state maintained by the pthreads library.  If it hasn't been initialized, that pointer would be garbage so the `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()` call might corrupt the heap.

See the [`pthread_attr_init()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_destroy.3.html) function to see how to properly initialize the attributes object.